# Why is the fan in my electric oven rubbing on the heating element?

Tags: electrical, oven

A Lamona oven fan seems to be catching on the element - making a loud scraping noise.

These is no gap at all between the fan and element- so no wonder it’s scraping.

Can’t adjust the element position. It seems odd the element would distort its shape so much?  Assume replacing the element will fix things?
[image: **Lamona fan **]

Comment: Has the fan motor shifted? You'll want to get a look underneath.

Comment: Otherwise I'd assume warpage due to heating cycles. I'd try gently flexing it into a better shape before paying for a new element.

Comment: Are you sure the fan blade is rubbing on the heating element?  In our LG stove, the axle for the blade had some in and out movement in the motor that was causing a rubbing sound.  Replacing the motor fixed the problem.

Comment: You can adjust the element, you can bend it like a champ...

Comment: Before attempting to bend the element itself, I'd suggest attempting to bend the mounting clips to move the whole element down & left slightly. Of course, there will be _some_ bending in the element. It's odd how the element is fairly flat on the top right, instead of reasonably round like the rest - has it always been that way?